# New at Git .. please give suggesstion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have MVC project which was already on git or in git whatever i don't know. Than i formatted my PC and than again install Git. but I don't know How actually it works. i gone through many tutorials and blogs but it is not happening.

As my project was already in GIT. so i have **.git** folder in my Project. and also have **.gitignore** file.

which have following data:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Roslyn cache directories
*.ide/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

#NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
 _ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding addin-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
## TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your
## web deploy settings but do note that will include unencrypted
## passwords
#*.pubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
packages/*
## TODO: If the tool you use requires repositories.config
## uncomment the next line
#!packages/repositories.config

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since
# NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets.
 # This line needs to be after the ignore of the build folder
 # (and the packages folder if the line above has been uncommented)
!packages/build/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

 # Backup & report files from converting an old project file
 # to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
 # because we have git ;-)
 _UpgradeReport_Files/
 Backup*/
 UpgradeLog*.XML
 UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml
/Marketplace/DesignTemplates/NC Tourism Beta/extractedfiles/backend/
/Marketplace/DesignTemplates/NC Tourism Beta/prod/backend/
*.bak
*.png
*.db
*.jpg
```

My project folder resides in F:/MarketPlace/MarketPlace path.
And I written following Commands in GItBash..

```
Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 ~
$ cd..
bash: cd..: command not found

Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 ~
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Sadhana/.git/

Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 ~ (master)
 $ .gitignore
bash: .gitignore: command not found

Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ cd C:Users/sadhana/.git

Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 /c/Users/sadhana/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ git init --bare marketplace.git
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Sadhana/.git/marketplace.git/

Sadhana@Viprak-Sadhana MINGW64 /c/Users/sadhana/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ .gitignore
bash: .gitignore: command not found
```

Now what should i do for my project to be run.

Comment: .gitignore isn't a command, it's a file that lists what you want git to ignore. `git init` creates a new empty git repository. If you have an existing repository, you need to check it out. Did you push your repository anywhere before formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .git folder is usable, you should see the name of the branch in git bash upon changing your directory to the folder where .git is located.  You should not need to execute the 'git init' command, since this will create a new .git folder.  It sounds like what you want to do is recover the existing repository, so we need to determine if your previous .git folder contains anything valuable.

Also, .gitignore is the file where you can specify files that should not be included in changesets.

Try navigating to 'C:Users/sadhana/' and see if git bash picks up on the repository in the .git folder.  You'll see the name of the branch if it goes well :)